# How to set ScrollView to the initial position programmatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have 6 buttons on a scroll view and when the user presses on of the buttons all of the buttons change title like a menu. However I would like the ScrollView to reset it self to the top, so the first few buttons are visible and the user is able to scroll down once again.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UIScrollView`? There are methods and properties related to setting the scroll position.

Comment: I've often wondered @rmaddy if you can do this *in storyboard*.  it seems to default to "top left" initially, and it seems impossible to change that in storyboard - as a curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a scrollView, simply change `scrollView.contentOffset` to move your scroll view's visible window. Like `x:0, y:0` to the top.

You should read some documents to understand `contentOffset`, `contentSize` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

`self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:250, y:100)`

x and y are the respective width and height from the top left corner of your scrollview.
[Apple documentation on contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset)